# REST Service ClassNotFoundException (com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer)

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I`m using java and eclipse to make a simple rest service. I use jersey 1.19 and jackson 1.7.9. But when i try to run project with tomcat i have this exception.

> SEVERE: Servlet [jersey-servlet] in web application [/EmployeeService] threw load() exception
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:506)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:488)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:115)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1148)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5262)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5550)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Here i will copy the classes and web.xml which i have.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
```

@XmlRootElement(name = "employee")
public class Employee {

```
public String empId;
public String name;
public String email;

@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement(required = true)
public String getEmpId() {
    return empId;
}

public void setEmpId(String empId) {
    this.empId = empId;
}

@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement(required = true)
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement(required = true)
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
```

}

@Path("/emp")
public class EmployeeService {

```
@GET
@Path("/get/{empId}")
public Employee getEmployee(@PathParam("empId") String empId) {
    Employee employee = new Employee();
    employee.setEmpId(empId);
    employee.setName("Nikola");
    employee.setEmpId("nikola@nikola.com");

    return employee;
}

@POST
@Path("/create")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public Employee createEmployee(Employee employee) {
    // create logic goes here
    return employee;
}

@PUT
@Path("/update")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Employee updateEmployee(Employee employee) {
    // create logic goes here
    employee.setName(employee.getName() + "updated");
    return employee;
}

@DELETE
@Path("/delete/{empId}")
public javax.ws.rs.core.Response deleteEmployee(@PathParam("empId") int empId) throws URISyntaxException {
    return javax.ws.rs.core.Response.status(200).entity("Employee with " + empId + "is deleted successfully").build();
}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    EmployeeProvider
    
        index.html
        index.htm
        index.jsp
        default.html
        default.htm
        default.jsp

```
<servlet>   
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.rest.employee</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Do you have the `jersey-servlet-1.19.jar`?

Comment: Yep, i`ve add that jar :)

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue. I put all jar into referenced libraries. but you have to Just copy-paste all required jar files into WEB-INF/lib folder. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

We get this error because of build path issue.You should add "Server Runtime" libraries in Build Path.

**"java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer"**

Please follow below steps to resolve class not found exception.

**Right click on project --> Build Path --> Build Path --> Add Library --> Server Runtime --> Apache Tomcat v7.0**

and yeah, remove load on startup tag.

It should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

you should remove this on your web.xml

```html
 <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer as to why would this help?

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you have added the jersey-servlet-1.19.jar but is it in your build path?