# Class not found even though it is clearly visible in Web App Libraries

Tags: java, servlets, jersey, java-ee-8

[Similar question exists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29185385/12169560) but none of the answers helped.

Starting Tomcat Server 9 on my Eclipse Project gives the error

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.class
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1364)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1187)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:539)
```

Even though I can clearly see `ServletContainer.class` under `org.glassfish.jersey.servlet` under `jersey-container-servlet-core.jar` under `Web App Libraries`.

All the required jars were added to `/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib`, they seem to be properly imported.

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="4.0">
  <display-name>JavaAPI</display-name>
  
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>JAVA API</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.class</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>test</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup> <!-- Tried Removing this, no difference -->
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>JAVA API</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Hello.java:

```
package test;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@Path("/hello")
public class Hello {
    
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
    public String sayHello() {
        String resource = "<? xml version='1.0' ?>" + 
                    "<hello>Hi Varun! This is the sayHello call.</hello>";
        return resource;
    }
    
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String sayHelloJSON() {
        String resource = null;
        return resource;
    }
    
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String sayHelloHTML() {
        String resource = "<h1>Hi Varun! This is the sayHelloHTML call.</h1>";
        return resource;
    }
}
```

Project Structure:
[image: Project Structure]

Using:

- Eclipse: 2021-03
- Tomcat: 9
- Java: 1.8 (set under BuildPath, ProjectFacets)
- JAX-RS 2.0 / Jersey 2.25.x

No Maven, Gradle involved, simply web project, with every jar hand-picked and imported.

Was following [this tutorial step-by-step](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5jQSat1cKMo).

Comment: P.S I am at my wit's end, very close to pulling my hair, whenever I have to do anything related to JavaEE, there's always some nuanced problem which is out of my mental grasp to solve. I am sorry if this is the wrong place to voice this, but I am for the first time in my life literally aggressively frustrated. No matter which tutorial I follow, no matter how simple they are even if I follow them step by step, there's always some weird bug that pops up and stalls me.

If your answers don't help just tell me how frustrating JavaEE was for you, It'll make me feel better.

Comment: Do you have one you would recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the .class suffix

```
<servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
```

instead of

```
<servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.class</servlet-class>
```

You specifiy the class name, not the class object.

Comment: I had tried this before, the console gets rilddled with multistack exceptions. But the webservice **does* return the function with ```MediaType.TEXT_HTML```'s value. So I am guessing something is going terribly wrong.

Comment: I'm not saying this is the only issue, but this solves the class not found issue